# Model built in foreach loop is null when passed to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am having an issue capturing the model when it's passed from the view to the controller.
Basically, every **Question** has a set of **QuestionResponse** (think of it as the list of offered responses for a certain question in a dropdown). **ClinicalSummaryAnswer** is the structure capturing one response per question, for a given user. So a user ends up with a collection of ClinicalSummaryAnswer, where every element is an answer to the respone.

When I submit the form below, all the elements in the model ClinicalSummaryView (ClinicalSummaryAnswer, Questions, QuestionResponse) are null from the controller side. Any ideas why this could happening? I suspect it may be due to the foreach? I am not sure. Please help!!

**My View**

```
 @model TissueBankApp.Models.View.ClinicalSummaryView
    
    
    
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ClinicalSummary", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {

<div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Person.PersonId" value="Person.PersonId" />
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" />
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Person" asp-route-id="Person.PersonId" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Cancel</a>
        </div>
           
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <b> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClinicalSummary.Description)  </b>
                </div>
    
                @foreach (var question in Model.Questions) //For every question, generate question, and generate responses
                {                        
            <div class="form-row">
                
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">@question.QuestionText</label>
    
                @if (question.QuestionResponse.Count() != 0) //If count ViewData[QID] != 0, generate select dropdown, otherwise, input.
    
                {            
    
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.ClinicalSummaryAnswer.FirstOrDefault(m => m.QuestionId == question.QuestionId).AnswerId, new SelectList(question.QuestionResponse, "ResponseId", "ResponseText"), "", new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })             
                }
                else
                {       
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.ClinicalSummaryAnswer.FirstOrDefault(m => m.QuestionId == question.QuestionId).OtherText, new { placeholder = "", @class = "form-control col-md-4", @type = "date" });
    
                }
            </div>
                }
    
            </div>
            
        }
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
      [HttpPost]
                [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
                public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ClinicalSummaryView viewModel, string[] AnswerId, string[] OtherText)
                { 
    
    //STUFF
//Ignore the OtherText, and AnswerId. I was testing to see if these are passed from view to controller and they are indeed. I just have no way of identifying which answer belongs to which question.
    }
```

Comment: how does your controller pass `model` to `view`?

Comment: You mean the other way round?

 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ClinicalSummaryView viewModel, string[] AnswerId, string[] OtherText)
        { //STUFF }

The interesting thing is that OtherText is populated with a list of strings from the input boxes, and AnswerId is populated with a list of the id's of answers chosen from the dropdown. I was just testing that out because when I Inspected element in the browser, all the input boxes/select had the same "name" (OtherText, and AnswerId)

Comment: your question contains too much noise information, can you remove them to be minimal?

Comment: I edited the code in the View to contain just the necessary info. Is that better? Or was the intro too much? I was just trying to explain the structure of the model to see if I could be binding the wrong way in the @Html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.Your backend wants to receive `ClinicalSummaryView.ClinicalSummaryAnswer` which is a list model. so what you pass should be `ClinicalSummaryAnswer[index].PropertyName`.

Change like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Person.PersonId" value="@Model.Person.PersonId"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" />
        <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Person" asp-route-id="@Model.Person.PersonId" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Cancel</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-row">
            <b> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClinicalSummary.Description)  </b>
        </div>
        @{ var i = 0;}      //add here...
        @foreach (var question in Model.Questions) 
        {               
            <div class="form-row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">@question.QuestionText</label>
                @if (question.QuestionResponse.Count() != 0) 

                {
                    //change here....               
                    @Html.DropDownList("ClinicalSummaryAnswer["+i+ "].AnswerId", new SelectList(question.QuestionResponse, "ResponseId", "ResponseText"), new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
                }
                else
                {
                    //change here....  
                    @Html.TextBox("ClinicalSummaryAnswer["+i+"].OtherText",null, new { placeholder = "", @class = "form-control col-md-4", @type = "date" });

                }
            </div>
            i++;  //add here...
        }
    </div>                    
 }
```

Besides, the following code should be modify:

```
                                         //change the value     
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Person.PersonId" value="@Model.Person.PersonId"/>   
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" />
                           //change asp-route-id here..
<a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Person" asp-route-id="@Model.Person.PersonId" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: I don't need the questionText (which is in label) to be passed. I need the values  of the selected options in the dropdown and the values in the different textboxes to be passed (Model.ClinicalSummaryAnswer , which is an ICollection). I think your modification does not address that issue. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @HK1232, it seems you do not want `string[] AnswerId, string[] OtherText` to receive data, you want to receive the dropdownlist and textbox data by `ClinicalSummaryView viewModel`. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Rena, thanks for the help. Sorry I forgot to check the thread, I solved the issue, I already had ClinicalSummaryView viewModel as an argument initially but it was all null. I managed to tweak it (I don't have the code in front of me atm). Thanks for the help regardless!